# Best moves for a 7X7 4 queen board

Tags: board-games

There is a 7x7 board and 2 players, each having 2 queens. The queens can move just like the queens in chess, but cannot capture each other. At the beginning, the first player places both the queens on any 2 different squares. Then the second player does the same with his queens. From this point, the players alternate turns, moving both queens each turn. When a queen is moved, the square that was previously occupied is now blocked and cannot be stood on or moved across for the remainder of the game. The first player who is unable to move any of his queens loses!

I am designing a player for it. What will be the strategy for the player who starts first or second? Also, what are best starting moves for any player?

Comment: When will the second player place the queens?

Comment: After the first player has placed his two queens. They alternate their turns

Comment: Can you please give an example for first 3,4 moves. Its hard to understand the rules.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL The first move could be (3,4) and (5,5) for player 1 and then move for player 2 could be (1,2) and (2,2)

Comment: It's still unclear for me if a player should move both his queens on his turn, or only one of them. Please clarify!

Comment: @elias Both of his queens

Comment: Since "the queens can move just like the queens in chess", can they also capture the opposing queens?

Comment: @Bass No. As the question says the end will be: "The first player who is unable to move any of his queens loses!"

Comment: I made a suggested edit to clarify the rules. If I got anything wrong please edit or roll back.

Comment: If I have two queen in A1 and B1 can I make the queen in A1 move into C1? At the same time I choose to move my queen in B1 in C3! In other word are the moves of the two queen (of the same color) simultaneous or sequential.

Comment: @Untitpoi How does it matter?

Comment: didn't read the "can't move across" part sry, so I guess they can't.

Comment: @SuhailGupta I hope that [this](https://www.quora.com/How-would-the-game-of-chess-be-affected-if-we-remove-a-row-from-the-chess-board/answer/D-Michael-McIntyre)  answers most of your doubts. 


  [1]: